# PyCharm: Adding carets above or below the current caret using keyboard is not working

Tags: pycharm, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, multiline, caret

In PyCharm, as I have to edit multiple lines at once, I've been trying to add carets below the current caret using a keyboard. As per [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html):

> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice, and then without releasing it, press up or down arrow keys.

However, when I do that, the text just gets scrolled. The cursor/caret is not moving at all.

The afore-mentioned page, also says:

> To add carets exactly above or below the current caret position using virtual spaces, press <kbd>Alt+Shift+Up</kbd> / <kbd>Alt+Shift+Down</kbd>.

I even tried that but in this case, the cursor moves to somewhat random places in the file.

Note that I can insert carets above or below the current caret using a mouse (<kbd>Alt+Shift</kbd> + `mouse-click` + `dragging the mouse`). However, I want to do that using the keyboard only... just like in VSCode, it's quite straightforward:

- to add Cursor Above: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>
- to add Cursor Below: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>

Comment: Future editors: Please note that I have put 'PyCharm' in the title mainly for providing more context. I'm not treating it as a tag over there because as you can see, I haven't put all the tags in the title. Please see some high-rated comments in this meta SE answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/775056

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the [keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-keymap.html) you use, the actions can have a default keyboard shortcut configured or you may have to configure it yourself.

You can configure these actions by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Keymap` `>` `Editor Actions`. In the IDE, the actions to add a caret exactly one line above or below the current caret position are called `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below` respectively.

In the screenshot, the default Windows keymap is used. As can be seen, the actions don't have default values and the keyboard shortcuts mentioned in the documentation are used for other actions. However, if you configure them, they work as expected.

[image: screenshot of settings]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response! I wish the PyCharm team had put a note on [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html): "By default, this shortcut won't work. They have to be added/overwritten manually". Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: @Milan you're welcome. The PyCharm mods are actually [active here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pycharm/topusers) some of them are on the top user list. They do an amazing job, especially with Python because the language itself changes considerable with every minor version (for example [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) have been changing so fast it's hard to keep up with the changes). I'm glad you found the answer useful, for me it was difficult understanding the IDE coming from Java, C#.

Comment: @Milan I accepted your edit but kept the backticks around `>` I've been asked about this in chat by experienced users and explained that in my view it makes formatting more consistent and slightly helps readability.

Comment: I'm still not that experienced with SO. Therefore, until now, I didn't know that I can see top users for a specific tag. Thank you for sharing that. Kudos to you as well... you are top on the list of the top active users for the last 30 days!! I also didn't have much idea about type hints in Python. Thanks for that as well as for your time :)

Comment: Oh, I got your point regarding the backticks around ">". Personally, in the above context, I like them without backticks. However, it's not a big deal and as you pointed out, the experienced users also like them with backticks `>`. Thank you so much again for taking the time in clarifying that... I appreciate it :)